# Blender ID Authentication Fail To Log In

Tags: blender-id

I have been using the "Blender ID authentication" and "Blender Cloud" Add-ons for a very long time without any issue until today.

I use these addons to save my custom "keymap", theme and other personal preferences.

Today, I change some short cut keys to fit my need and as always I always save these setting onto the "cloud". However, I stumbled on this weird error.

[image]
*Please click on the picture to extend it*

Comment: It looks like a temporary misconfiguration on their login server.